# Install wordcloud in jetbrains pycharm with python version 3.6 failed

Tags: python, pip, word-cloud

I am trying to install wordcloud in pycharm (pip install wordcloud) with python 3.6 in terminal but getting this error. I install every library in terminal with pip install statement but failed to install wordcloud. How can I solve this?

```
(venv) C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api>pip install wordcloud
Collecting wordcloud
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/9f/27cec92eee9f1d4f02f986ad0cc6dfc0797b117be6e968da8f92c6c183aa/wordcloud-1.7.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\mansi dhingra\desktop\projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib->wordcloud)
Installing collected packages: wordcloud
  Running setup.py install for wordcloud ... error
    Complete output from command "C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MANSID~1\\AppData\\Local\\T
emp\\pip-build-hzywsg3f\\wordcloud\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --r
ecord C:\Users\MANSID~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-otlfw3d1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects
\api\venv\include\site\python3.7\wordcloud":
    C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\color_from_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\tokenization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\wordcloud.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\wordcloud_cli.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\stopwords -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\DroidSansMono.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud/_version.py
    set build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud/_version.py to '1.7.0'
    running build_ext
    building 'wordcloud.query_integral_image' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MANSID~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hzywsg3f\
\wordcloud\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MANSID~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-otlfw3d1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api\venv\include\site\p
ython3.7\wordcloud"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MANSID~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hzywsg3f\wordcloud\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wordcloud` 1.7.0](https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud/1.7.0/#files) provides a lot of wheels for w32 but not for Python 3.8. My advice downgrade to Python 3.7 64-bit.

If you want to install wordcloud for Python 3.8 you must have [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required) to compile C/C++ modules.